# How to programmatically test whether BLE is advertising in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to unit test the advertising part of the BLE in android. But I couldn't find out to check whether the BLE is broadcasting or not.

Comment: could you please post what you've tried so far?

Comment: This brief Q and one-line answer needs more substance to make it worth keeping - flesh it out with information to make it useful for others in the future! What Beacon library are using? Or are you using Android built in BLE peripheral APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.It was quite simple and straight forward.
I used

`Beacons.isInitialized();`

It returns a boolean value. Also not forget to handle NullPointer Exception.